# what is happening to this python char array

Tags: python-2.7, operators

```
str = "hello this is a string"
buffer = map(ord,str) #string to char array
b = (buffer[0]) #i assume this is creating an array of one buffer[0]
fin = b & 0x80 #what does this do?
```

I am not sure what `b & 0x80` is doing, i am assuming it is appending the `b` byte array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right what the most of the code is doing:

```
str = "hello this is a string"
buffer = map(ord,str)
print buffer
```

Buffer is a list where each character in `str` got changed into it's ascii value (even spaces get converted, they have value 32):

```
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 116, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 97, 32, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]
```

The next line just sets `b` to be the first index of this list, so `b` is just an int, not a list of int. The parens don't matter:

```
b = (buffer[0])
bb = buffer[0]
print b,bb #prints: 104 104
```

The `&` is a bitwise "and" operator which works by taking two numbers and returning a new number with bits on only for overlapping bits. The binary of `104` is:

```
print("{0:b}".format(104))
'01101000'
```

The `0x80` is hexadecimal for `128` which has binary string `'10000000'`. So the `&` of 104 and 128 is the columns where both numbers, written in binary, have a `1`, which happens to be none, so the result is zero:

```
'01101000'
'10000000'
 --------
'00000000'
```

Here is an example between `128` and `129` which results in the answer `128`:

```
'10000000'
'10000001'
 --------
'10000000'
```